# Создание задачи автоматического запуска приложения

Tags: windows, администрирование, планировщик-задач

Мне требуется организовать автоматический запуск приложения с правами администратора при включении компьютера.

Пытаюсь это реализовать с помощью Планировщика заданий Windows:

Создаю задачу...

- Во вкладке "Общее" отмечаю "Выполнять для всех пользователей", "Выполнять с наивысшими правами"
- Во вкладке "Триггеры" добавляю условие старта задачи при запуске компьютера
- В "Действия" добавляю запуск некоторой программы (да хотя бы notepad.exe)
- Из "Условий" убираю "Запускать только при питании от электросети"
- Сохраняю

После перезагрузки компьютера и входа в систему я ожидал увидеть окно запущенного приложения, которое я указал. Но этого не происходит! В чём заключается ошибка?

Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибок как минимум две.

Первая - желая запуска приложения при включении (старте) компьютера (рабочей станции), Вы создаёте задание в профиле пользователя (учётной записи).

Вторая - даже если создать запись там, где нужно согласно поставленной задаче, окно приложения увидеть всё равно не удастся. При его старте произойдёт загрузка профиля требуемой учётной записи, включая формирование экземпляра рабочего стола (да и то при условии, что все необходимые для этого параметры запуска указаны - иначе роль рабочего стола сыграет вульгарный Null). Это вовсе не тот рабочий стол, который создаётся при аутентификации пользователя, даже если это формально та же учётная запись, от имени которой запущено приложение. Даже два одинаковых задания - и то у каждого будет свой рабстол, недоступный второй копии...

PS. Компьютер тупой, и почему-то делает то, что ты скажешь, а не то, что хочешь. Но в данном случае, по-моему, автор даже не до конца понимает, что же он на самом деле хочет...

Comment: Как мне кажется задача обозначена достаточно чётко: требуется организовать автоматический запуск приложения с правами администратора при включении компьютера. Мне просто нужен автозапуск, но с правами администратора и без запроса UAC (каждый раз в смысле).

Comment: Как мне показалось, Планировщик заданий для этого подходит. Но как правильно всё сделать я не знаю... Вы перечислили ошибки, но не дали решения. Что вы можете посоветовать?

Comment: *автозапуск, но с правами администратора и без запроса UAC.* Галка "Выполнять с наивысшими правами" подавляет запрос UAC. Галку "Выполнять для всех пользователей" снимите. И чётко понимайте - даже если приложение оконное, его окна Вы не увидите и взаимодействовать с ним не сможете. Хотя оно запустится и будет видно в списке работающих процессов.

Comment: Если создать задачу запуска программы, которая просто создаёт текстовый файл, запустить задачу, то почему файл не создаётся?

Comment: Видимо он создаётся. Но не там где надо. Не в одной папке с программой, а в директории SysWOW64. Почему так происходит и возможно ли исправить не изменяя код программы?

Comment: Так же у меня всё таки не получается создать задачу автозапуска своей программы. Вот скрины настроек созданной задачи: https://ibb.co/kEsP46, https://ibb.co/jeyxP6, https://ibb.co/gWtmHR, https://ibb.co/hAJWj6, https://ibb.co/n4HP46. Процесса в Диспетчере задач я после перезагрузи своего ПК не наблюдаю...

Comment: *создаётся. Но не там где надо. Не в одной папке с программой, а в директории SysWOW64. Почему так происходит* Потому что перед созданием файла надо выполнить явно переход на нужный том в нужный каталог - без указания пути файл пишется в текущий каталог. Или указывать полный путь файла, а не только имя. Или указать хотя бы рабочую папку в свойствах задания...

Comment: Хорошо. А что на счёт автозапуска?